# Custom Cell Selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am drawing a custom cell, to achieve a certain look I want.  However, I want to perform a different drawing based on if the cell is select.  I really do not just want the default colors.

I changed content's views background color the view in this method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

However, it just did not appear correctly, mainly it did not take into account the accessary and just colored it until the accessory indicator.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{        
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Background
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0f, rect.size.height);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    // Top line
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, CELL_TOP_LINE_COLOR);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CELL_LINE_WIDTH);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    //Bottom line
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, CELL_BOTTOM_LINE_COLOR);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CELL_LINE_WIDTH);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works great, it also draws underneath the default accessory views, like the accessory indicator.  I created custom view's called BackgroundView and SelectedBackgroundView, I just use the drawRect method to create a custom drawing.  It works great, and performance seems to be okay.  If anyone wants to see the full code let me know.

```
[cell setBackgroundView:[[BackgroundView alloc] init]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[SelectedBackgroundView alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your `drawRect` method and change how your color are set depending of the `isSelected` property. Changing the content's view background when the setSelected method will probably don't change anything since it will be overriding by the `drawRect` method.

Comment: I'm trying that however, when I switch screens, the cell will change the same color, I can't think of an efficient way to handle this

Comment: Did you try forcing the redrawing of the selected cell by any chance - maybe with a setNeedsDisplay on ur selected cell. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, the problem with this method is when you select a cell, you leave you finger on the spot you select, but the cell won't highlight until you let your finger off the screen, not sure if there is a way around that

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this :

```
if(self.highlighted || self.selected) {
    //set text color
    textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

    //set background color
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);
}
```

Also check `selectionStyle`property of your cell.

Comment: Is this in the drawRect method?

Comment: And i'm assuming you set the selectionStyle to none, and call setNeedsDisplay in the didSelectRow?

Comment: In my current project I have UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray and in the didSelectRow I call deselectRow only. If I don't call deselectRow, cell stays in selected mode. On finger down it's actually in highlighted state.

Comment: Are you setting highlighted or selected, because those are not getting set for me?

Comment: When I select a row in the table, the drawRect method is not getting called, but your's is?

Comment: If you want to manually select the cell, you have to use selectRowAtIndexPath, or with the finder with didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Can you check whether drawContentView is called?

Comment: Thanks for the help I actually found a solution, I custom draw a background view, and a selected view then set the cell's properties for background view, and selected view